# Apex Post not accepting setBody

Tags: apex, webservices, httppost

```
 public static HttpResponse getIntegratedInfoFromExternalService(String WebURL , String key) {
         Http h = new Http();
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(WebURL);
        req.setBody('key=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(key,'UTF-8'));
        req.setMethod('POST');
       req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');       


        try{
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            System.debug(res.getBody());
             return res;
        }catch(System.CalloutException e){
            System.debug('Callout Exception' + e);

             return null;
        }
```

If I write a Get request it works fine. However, if **I write a Post request with a set body containing the key**. It doesn't process the key values. If I write the Post request with the endpoint including the key but without the set body it works fine.

I want to write a Post request with a set body containing the key.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the problem with this code:

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://requestb.in/16cfwpa1');
req.setBody('key=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode('foo','UTF-8'));
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

https://requestb.in/16cfwpa1?inspect

Are you sure key is passed correctly?

Comment: How do you set the page Reference for Post Request

Comment: Hey @DominicSeb not sure what are you asking, but perhaps `req.setBody( Page.YOURVISUALFORCEPAGENAME.getContent().toString() );`